# Code changes in Netbeans not reflected in project

Tags: php, html, css, netbeans

Often times while working in Netbeans the changes I make in my code are not visible in the actual project. I'm working on a website using HTML/PHP and a lot of times, I make certain changes to my code, save it and then when I open the website in my browser it's like I never made any changes. It's really frustrating. Please help.

PS: I've noticed it mostly happens when I make changes to the CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would think of blaming Netbeans. Or you for not letting Netbeans upload changes to the server on Save.

But if it is mostly CSS (and I suppose Javascript), I would think of caching by your browser.

You can try Ctrl-F5 -in your browser- for forced refresh.
Or set the cache settings on your development server so, that a file is never cached